# how to store all days beween two days using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i need to store all the days between two dates in an ARRAY.

for eg:

`from_date is: 2014-09-20,` `to_date : 2014-09-24`

the result will be

```
2014-09-20, 2014-09-21, 2014-09-22, 2014-09-23, 2014-09-24.
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: how are you getting the two date values?

Comment: Dim fdate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dtFrom.Text)            

        Dim tdate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dtTo.Text)

        Dim BtwDates As String = ""

        For Each [date] As DateTime In GetDateRange(fdate, tdate)

           BtwDates += [date].ToString("dd") + ";"

        Next

Comment: the dates are chosen by user from front-end.

Answer (score 1):

One way: LINQ

```
Dim days = From day In Enumerable.Range(0, (toDate - fromDate).Days + 1)
           Select fromDate.AddDays(day)
Dim result As Date() = days.ToArray()
```

The classic way without math which also works in .NET 2:

```
Dim dayList As New List(Of Date)
Dim currentDate = fromDate
While currentDate <= toDate
    dayList.Add(currentDate)
    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)
End While
Dim result As Date() = dayList.ToArray()
```

If you need a `string()` as commented just append `ToString()`. For example:

```
Dim days = From day In Enumerable.Range(0, (toDate - fromDate).Days + 1)
           Select fromDate.AddDays(day).ToString()
Dim result As String() = days.ToArray()
```

Comment: How can i store this to string array ?

Comment: Just append ToString() after AddDays(). But why do you need to store it as a wrong type? You should only convert it to a string at the last stage, when you  display it.

Comment: @Indrah: however, i've edited my answer to show you how.